# Pragma use in across dll

Tags: c#, pragma

I have a main Program A which calls a dllB method.

dllB is build in release mode.
Depending on which mode the Program A is build(Release/Debug) the result should be returned appropriately but it always returns "releaseMode".

So is there a way where i can reference dllB in release mode and depending on the main program preference(Release/Debug) get the result.

```
Program A---
main ()
{
  var dllbObj = new dllB();
  var response = dllObj.CallMethod();
 //Release mode should return "releaseMode" 
 //and debug mode should return "debugMode"
}

dll B---
public string CallMethod()
{
 string res;
#if DEBUG
            res = "debugMode";
#endif
            res = "releaseMode";

            return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this with pragmas, because they are baked into the assembly at compile-time. If the second assembly is compiled in Release mode, it doesn't contain any code that might have been placed in a DEBUG section.

Comment: Thanks Darin but then what is the best way to use 2 dlls one for debug and one for release.Can you suggest.

Comment: If you have the source code of the second assembly you could recompile it according to the mode of the main assembly. If you don't, then you simply don't have the source code of this secondary assembly for the DEBUG mode, so you can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to accomplish this as A.exe and B.dll are compiled independently of each other.  When `B` is compiled in Release the `"debugMode"` string simply won't exist in B.dll in any shape or form.  It is completely ignored by the compiler.

The only way to have `A.exe` get the debug or release string from `B.dll` is to have them both match on their compilation.  Either compile them both in Debug or both in Release but don't mix it.